# What dataset is being used when Tensorflow Estimator prints the loss

Tags: logging, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

When using Tensorflow Estimator it prints on the python console (each 100 steps) the global step and the loss (and in addition it prints the learning rate, the cross-entropy and the MAE which is my evaluation metric and it prints these 3 values in a different line which I think is due to some wrapper function which is not part of the original Estimator API because I'm using an Implementation of ResNet by google's developers). It looks like this:

```
    I0530 19:20:42.748463 10964 tf_logging.py:116] learning_rate = 3.552962e-05, cross_entropy = 2.2080934, MAE = 5.135024 (62.295 sec)   
    I0530 19:20:42.749458 10964 tf_logging.py:116] loss = 2.2080934, step = 76066 (62.295 sec)
```

My question is, what loss is being computed (or what MAE is being computed)?
Is it the loss on just one example at the specific step when the logging occur?
Is it the loss on a batch at the specific step when the logging occur?
Or maybe it is the loss on the whole train set?

Also, please correct me if I'm assuming something wrong. I'm quite new in this field.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.Estimator` automatically sets up a `LoggingTensorHook` for the loss as well as the global step. Presumably, the code you run sets up a separate hook for the other values (learning rate, cross entropy (which is just the loss) and MAE), which is why they are printed on separate lines.

As to what data is used to produce the values: It's the "current" batch of data, i.e. the batch that was used in the step where logging is done. So, out of the three options you proposed, the second one is correct.

This can be confimed via [the source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py#L255), as the hook does logging "after run", receiving the results of the last `session.run()` call (wich only gets one batch at a time) in `run_values`.